# Twenty-two points of attack

Tags: translation, pronunciation

How do I say "Twenty-two points of attack" in Japanese? Rather new at Japanese so any help would be greatly appreciated.

*Edit.*

...and since it was put on hold, I will edit in my "research".

The only translation I could find was in Kanji which is 攻撃の 20 2 点. So I then researched the kanji character translations and found a site that actually had mp3 sound bites of how the characters are spoken.

攻撃 
I found to mean "attack" (in the proper context I was trying to achieve). 攻 - spoken translation meaning "kou" and 撃 - spoken translation meaning "geki". I put the two together and searched for a translation of the word and, low and behold, "kougeki" was translated as "attack".

の
Similar research, similar results... spoken translation "no", translated to "of"

20 2 
...well "22". I am a little familiar with counting in Japanese so I attempted this one on my own and since the Kanji separated the "20" and the "2" I translated to "niju ni". A quick search proved my counting knowledge to be somewhat accurate so was satisfied with the result.

点
...this one was a bit trickier. Translated to "points". I could not locate this character so researched "points" with no results. However, I could find "point" which resulted in a spoken translation of "kyoten".

Now to put it all together...

Much like other languages, I noticed the Kanji is NOT in order so I can only assume that the translation to Japanese would be...

"kougeki no niju ni kyoten" (or at least close to it??)

As I previously stated, I am fairly new at the Japanese language but very interested in learning.

I hope my "research" will satisfy those who put the topic "on hold" to generate a proper response to see if I am on the right track.

Comment: No offense, but translating word-for-word almost never works, especially translating a head-initial, verbose, analytic languages like English to a head-final, pro-drop, agglutinative languages like Japanese!

Comment: I am amazed on how much effort you put into translating an abstract concept into a language you do not know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「22攻撃ポイント」 is how I would phrase it, and if it means anything, I am a native speaker.

It looks awkward to use a particle like 「の」 in a short phrase like this, and "20 2" is just not a possibility.

Comment: I actually had this as one translation meaning "22 attack points". I was also skeptical about the "20 2" which was the result an online translator gave. Though I appreciate your response, I still would like to know how to verbally speak the phrase. Would I be correct in saying "Nijuu ni kougeki kyoten" ???

Comment: If you're asking how to read "22攻撃ポイント", it's pronounced "ni juu ni kougeki pointo"

Comment: I recommend http://translate.weblio.jp/ if you really want machine translation. It really understands the English sentence and outputs always correct (although sometimes it misunderstands the english) Japanese! WAAAAY better than Google Translate. It translates it into "攻撃の22ポイント" (kougeki-no nijūni pointo) which is quite correct although perhaps unidiomatic.

Comment: Thank you for the link user54609! I didn't use Google Translate but did get the result you provided. As seen in the OP, my result was fairly close (kougeki no niju ni kyoten). With the help of users here, I now have several ways the phrase can be spoken including the proper way from a native speaker! Thanks to you all as this really helped and is greatly appreciated! :)